# How do I get one element to respond to the click of another element? - CSS/jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

The question is simple, but in my implementation something has gone awry.

You can see my implementation [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Bdh5k/).

So what I want to happen is, when you click on one of the names in box #1, the dotted line and the #1 in a dotted circle both turn black and solid. The dotted line is not a border. The same should happen when you click any other data in the other corresponding boxes.

The main issue I am facing is that when I do a use the .css function in jQuery to manually change the color and the border, it works nicely. However, I would like to modify it with the toggle class (because I couldn't get toggle() to work with the css function) - so that when you click it once, you see the element clicked highlighted (with a 1px border - this functionality is already there), and the corresponding number for the box (and dotted line) turned to solid black.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the JavaScript was fine. The only thing I could see messing things up was this line:

```
$('#bc1 dashed-circle').toggleClass('bc-dashed-to-solid-circle');
```

You'll want to change that selector to `#bc1 .dashed-circle`.

The reason the dashes and number aren't changing color is because of specificity. You declare their normal color (#bdbebf) with the selector `#blank-dashboard-breadcrumb span` -- an id and an element. You declare the "selected" color (black) with `.bc-dotted-to-solid` or `.bc-dashed-to-solid-circle` -- simple classes. Even when the dash and the 1 have the appropriate classes, they still have a more specific selector telling them to remain gray.

Comment: I knew my problem was something like this. The question is...how do I fix this ? I included your solution and it doesn't do what I need it to. Any further suggestions on how I can actually get the functionality I want? I think you are on the right track.

Comment: Well, another thing I noticed was that you're applying the click listener to all the different trs, but they all change the class on only the first number. Is that the problem you're referring to? When you say that the solution doesn't do what you need it to, what do you mean?

Comment: What I mean is, the functionality I am looking for is: when you click on one of the names, I want the dotted line & corresponding number to change css. For instance, when you click 'John Brown', I want the first dotted-line to turn black and turn to a solid line - and I also want '#1' to change to black and the border to turn solid. That's what it's not doing, at the moment. I think it has something to do with the specificity you pointed out. But I am confused as to how to fix it.

Comment: Here's how I understand it (correct me if I'm wrong): When the user selects "John Brown," you want the one to be solid black. And when they keep selecting that name, you want it to stay black. When they select "Jack Dorsey," you want the 2 (and the dashes in between the 1 and the 2) to turn black. When they select "Jane Dempsey," the 3 turns black. Sound right?

Comment: I think I was wrong in my comment just above. [Here's a new jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BMWZd/2/) that I think does what you want.

Comment: Almost there sdleihssirhc. The last thing I need it to do, is when you click on 'John Brown', the action can be toggled. i.e. the css of the dashed line can be changed, but when they click it again, it can be toggled off. Btw, in this jsfiddle, the only thing you did was put a new class 'tr_class' in the stylesheet and wrote some new jQuery, right? Want to make sure I am not missing something.

Comment: [This should do it.](http://jsfiddle.net/BMWZd/3/) The jQuery is completely changed, but the only thing I did in the CSS (after making those specificity changes) was to get rid of the 5px border rule. The `tr_class` is just a JavaScript variable, because I didn't feel like typing out that long string a bunch of times.

Comment: I believe one of the major gems you did - that I overlooked - was changing the specificity of the css class I was trying to add. Specifically `#blank-dashboard-breadcrumb .bc-dotted-to-solid`